# Best way to get Firestore sub-collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access and show the entire sub-collection data and successfully use nested foreach.

Here is the path I want to access:
`users/${id}/posts`

Here is the code I use:

```
const collections = onSnapshot(query(colRef, orderBy('userLastSigned')), (coll) => {
    coll.docs.forEach((colls) => {
        const subsPostListsAlls = onSnapshot(query(collection(db, `users/${colls.id}/posts`), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')), (query) => {
            query.docs.forEach((queries) => {
                ...
```

Is there a better way than the one I'm using?

Comment: So to understand better, do you need to read all posts of all users?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I want to show all posts from all users. The code I've shown above actually works, but I don't think it's the best practice.

Comment: Did you try BeEmil's solution? To use a collection group?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use

replace: `collection(db, users/${colls.id}/posts)`

with: `collectionGroup(db, 'posts')`

You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: Now, the problem is with the security rules. can you show an example of the rule?

Comment: Did you see the [create rules that allow your collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups) that is also linked from the documentation?